# Load URL into array using Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I've a button where I can upload images to my app. And once I upload them they are stored into an array which contains URLs. 
Now I'm trying to retrieve the image from the URL and insert it into an imageview, and right after it will be inserted into an UIImage array. But it's always returns NIL.

First off, I'm getting the error, cuz it's an array:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

```
    if downloadURL != []
    {
        let url = URL(string: downloadURL) //ERROR HERE

        imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        imgArray.append(imageView.image!)

    }
```

So it crashes at the "imgArray.append" since imageView returns NIL.

downloadURL DOES have an URL so it's not nil.

Comment: seems like your `downloadURL ` is an array

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren Yeah, it is. But I need all of the URLs

Comment: Then you need a loop, like `downloadURL.forEach { url in ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to download all images, you have to do something like this:

```
for url in downloadURL {
    guard let imageURL = URL(string: url) else {
        continue 
    }
    imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)
    // to load images separately use this
    KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: imageURL) { result in
         let image = try? result.get().image
         if let image = image {
              imgArray.append(image)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: No result at all :/

Comment: I don’t think that you can add images like that, because loading images is asyncronous, I think you have to load images after kingfisher loads them

Comment: Do you have any idea how to?

Comment: Updated the answer, it’s not the best way but it should work

Comment: There we go! Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: How comes its not the best tho? I mean, what's bad with that?

Comment: You might set the images inside closure without using yhe extension. Where you append images to array, you can also set image to your imageView like `imageView.image = image`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize a `URL` with a `array`, `URL` need to be initialized with a `String`. (The error tells you clearly)

Also, `kf.setImage(with:)` need a `URL` to be initialized, not a `String`, so:

Try something like this:

```
if downloadURL.count > 0 {
        if let urlString = downloadURL.last { // I intuit that the url you want is the last one you appended 

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)

        if let image = imageView.image {
          imgArray.append(image) // Only append if the image was set conrrectly
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting another error which is: 

Cannot invoke 'setImage' with an argument list of type '(with: String)'

And yes, it's an array. But I has to retrieve ALL images from it

Comment: I edit my answer, set image need a URL instead of string.